# return a structure different from the declared structure, why can it be correct? C#

Tags: c#

I'm reading this piece of code:

```
private static WaveFormat WaveFormatFromBlob(Blob blob){
 if(blob.Length == 40)
    return (WaveFormatExtensible)Marshal.PtrToStructure(blob.Data, typeof(WaveFormatExtensible));                
 return (WaveFormat)Marshal.PtrToStructure(blob.Data, typeof (WaveFormat));
}
```

If the returnvalue is declared as WaveFormat, how can I return a WaveFormatExtensible? And the next question will be: How, in the calling routine, can I distinguish which type has been returned to me and choose the corresponding assignment? I need to change parameters in the one or the other, depending on of what type it is. I know it's basic c#, but I just don't get it.

Comment: Does `WaveFormatExtensible` inherit from `WaveFormat`?

Comment: yes; public class WaveFormatExtensible : WaveFormat

Comment: Structure types don't permit inheritance.  Use a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-multimedia-waveformatextensible), `WaveFormatExtensible` is a sub-type of `WaveFormat`:

```
public class WaveFormatExtensible : WaveFormat
```

So, what your seeing is called [*Liskov Substitution Principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming. It
>   states that, in a computer program, if **S (WaveFormatExtensible)** is a subtype of **T (WaveFormat)**, then
>   **objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S** (i.e.,
>   objects of type S may substitute objects of type T) without altering
>   any of the desirable properties of that program (correctness, task
>   performed, etc.).

Because `WaveFormatExtensible` derives from `WaveFormat`, it is eligible as a return type to the method.

Comment: and a: WaveFormatExtensible WE = (WaveFormatExtensible) T; upgrades my class, as I just tried!

Comment: What is the type of `T`?

Comment: WaveFormat T as written in he answer. Thought it was clear, sorry

Comment: @martin Only if the return type is the dervied `WaveFormatExtensible`. If its not, you'll get an `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that structure of the code looks like this basically

```
public class WaveFormatExtensible  : WaveFormat
{
   ...
}
```

Which means that from the method that returns base class `WaveFormat` you return an extended object `WaveFormatExtended`, by upper casting it to `WaveFormat`

Comment: And on top of it - this is a CLASS and not a STRUCT(ure).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757714(v=vs.85).aspx) says (emphasis mine):

> The WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE structure defines the format of waveform-audio data for formats having more than two channels or higher sample resolutions than allowed by WAVEFORMATEX. **It can also be used to define any format that can be defined by WAVEFORMATEX.**

So there is some compatibility between the two structs in C++. (In fact the `Format` of `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` is a `WAVEFORMATEX`).

I guess the mapping from C++ to C# implemented this as a *derived **class***, meaning that `WaveFormatExtensible` extends `WaveFormat`. If so, an instance of `WaveFormatExtensible` is a valid return type for `WaveFormat`.